# ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() with jre + tools.jar

Tags: annotations, java-8

Note: Its a repeat question from oracle forums as nobody answered it over there.

Our apps ships with a JRE and not a JDK and in the classpath we also have tools.jar.

From our app we compile the abc.java with the command: com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(file);

Then next step is that we do some annotation processing with the apt tool e.g.

```
args[0] = "-nocompile";
args[1]=abc.java
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int aptReturnCode = com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(processor, new PrintWriter(baos), fl); //where processor is the custom annotation processor.
```

With java-8 we have found that oracle have made the apt tool defunct so instead of using the apt tool we are supposed to use the java compiler for the same task.(I got this tip from this forum in the past) So I came up with code below which needed some reworking of the annotation processor but the problem is that `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler( )` always returns null. Is there any way that I could do this annotation processing or load the java compiler with just the tools.jar in the class path without using a jdk ?

```
ArrayList<String> customClasses = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> arguments = new ArrayList<String>();//arguments for the java compiler
arguments.add( "-proc:only" ); // only do annotations processing and do not compile the source code.
customClasses.add("full path/abc.java");

JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler(); // always returns null

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
  StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
  Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(customClasses);

  JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task =
  compiler.getTask(new PrintWriter(baos), fileManager, diagnostics, arguments, null, compilationUnits);

  ArrayList<Processor> processors = new ArrayList<Processor>();
  processors.add( new MyCustomProcessor() );
  task.setProcessors( processors );

  boolean success = task.call();
```

Many Thanks

Comment: You need the Java 8 version of `tools.jar` in your class path to make it work. But beware that this will *again* break as soon as you switch to Java 9 as then, there will be no `tools.jar` anymore (if everything’s rolled out as planned). So the bottom line is, if you need a compiler, you need a JDK (unless you have your own custom compiler).

Comment: We do have a java8 tools.jar in the app classpath but ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler(); still returns null

Comment: Try adding it to the bootstrap class path, i.e. [`-Xbootclasspath/a:path/to/tools.jar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BABHDABI)

Comment: Adding it to bootstrap class path seems to do the trick but without adding it to bootstrap it seems like I can also use com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool javac = com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.create(); Thanks :)

Comment: Well, both solutions are not portable and likely to break in a future version…

Comment: By 'not portable' , do you mean not portable across platforms and if so how ? thanks.

Comment: Not portable across different JRE/JDK implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up eclipse on windows, I have a project that uses mapstruct. I just want to note that if you are seeing this error in the maven console logs

> [ERROR] JVM is not suitable for processing annotation!
>   ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() is null.

One fix will be to

Install the java jdk, open up the eclipse.ini and add the following lines above the -vmargs

```
-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
```